# Time not measured properly in second algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, time

My task is to compere algorithm speed of program which searches array for 2 numbers that equal x.

Problem is that time measured with bruteforce has normal numbers

```
10000 0.292887
20000 1.13808
30000 2.57459
40000 4.5844
50000 7.16904
60000 10.2995
70000 15.4171
80000 19.8118
90000 24.5601
100000 30.2785
```

but for the algorithm below I get this:

```
10000 0.000488489
20000 0.000419209
30000 0.000539166
40000 0.000528902
50000 0.000538524
60000 0.000669387
70000 0.000701461
80000 0.000653029
90000 0.000603635
100000 0.000520563
```

Here's the code for the second algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

double PCFreq = 0.0;
__int64 CounterStart = 0;

void StartCounter()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    if (!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li))
        cout << "QueryPerformanceFrequency failed!\n";

    PCFreq = double(li.QuadPart);

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    CounterStart = li.QuadPart;
}

double GetCounter()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    return double(li.QuadPart - CounterStart) / PCFreq;
}

bool sum(int tab[], int l, int x)
{
    int left = 0;
    int right = l - 1;

    while (left < right)
    {
        if (tab[left] + tab[right] == x)
        {
            cout << "\n" << tab[left] << "+" << tab[right] << "=" << x;
            return 1;
        }
        else if (tab[left] + tab[right] < x)
            left++;
        else
            right--;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int l;
    int x;
    int temp;
    bool change;

    srand(time(NULL));

    cout << "=============================================================\n";

    cout << "Array Lenght: ";
    cin >> l;

    cout << "Looking for sum: ";
    cin >> x;

    int *tab = new int[l];

    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        tab[i] = (rand() * rand()) % 2147483647;
    }

    while (true)
    {
        change = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < l - 1; i++)
        {
            if (tab[i] > tab[i + 1])
            {
                change = true;
                temp = tab[i];
                tab[i] = tab[i + 1];
                tab[i + 1] = temp;
            }
        }

        if (!change)
            break;
    }

    long double time;

    StartCounter();

    if (sum(tab, l, x) == 1)
    {
        cout << " |||| Found sum";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Sum of 2 numbers not found";
    }
    time = GetCounter();

    ofstream data2;
    data2.open("data2.txt", ios::app);

    cout << "\nAlgorithmic efficiency:" << time;
    data2 << l << " " << time << endl;

    data2.close();
}
```

Why are the times so tiny and unrealistic for this?

Comment: It probably means your compiler has found a way to optimize the code because you've got undefined behaviour or never use some result or some other feature that allows the compiler to omit most of the working code.  I'm not sufficiently sure what your code is up to to want to pontificate further.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. In particular, remove all manual input. Further, even most of the output is probably irrelevant. Also, you say "these numbers are too small", but you neither give an expected value nor do your numbers have any units, which makes it hard to follow your interpretation.